# Why is my select option not getting disabled?

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown, select-options

I have a html page, which contains two select boxes. Both boxes contain the same options. Everytime one option is selected in one box, it should be disabled in the second box.

My first select box in my html file:

```
<div class="select_box">
    <select id="unallowedInput" onchange="disableOption()" class="select2 col-lg-12" multiple title="Auswählen" data-max-options="3" data-max-options-text="Es dürfen nur drei Elemente ausgewählt werden!"></select>       
</div>
```

Now my js file which contains a method to get the option values from an api and my method to disable the options:

```
function addToSelect(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.select2').selectpicker({
            liveSearch: true
         });
    })

    var input1 = document.getElementById('unallowedInput');                             

    var geturlW = 'myurl';
    var wirk = req('GET', geturlW);
    var length = Object.keys(wirk).length;                                  
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        var opt1 = document.createElement('option');
                            
        opt1.innerHTML = wirk[i].name;
        opt1.value = wirk[i].name;
        opt1.id = wirk[i].id;
        eingabe1.appendChild(opt1); 
    }
}
```

```
function disableOption(){
    document.getElementById("elem1").disabled = true;
    console.log(document.getElementById("elem1"));
}
```

I tried to start simple by just disabling the first element from the first box onchange:

```
document.getElementById("elem1").disabled = true;
```

It changes my option successfully from:

```
<option value="Option1" id="elem1">Option1</option>
```

to:

```
<option value="Option1" id="elem1" disabled="">Option1</option>
```

The problem is, that the element is still enabled.
Same goes when I use:

```
document.getElementById("elem1").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

Since I'm still a beginner and not really familiar with JQuery yet, I would appreciate it, if the answers would contain just plain JS :)

Comment: It looks fine to me. Can u show us the entire code? The on click event functions and all so that we can check if there's some other issue

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I tried to simulate the filling of the `select` and honestly everything seems to work correctly at the `onchange`. It could depend on the *browser* or other JavaScript conflicting (e.g. jQuery) or the variable **eingabe1** in your function which is not **input1** ...

[image]

---

Using your code it works properly (see image below, example with `elem2`):

```
document.getElementById("elem2").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

[image]

So i guess the problem is upstream, ie the moment you run that code. You are probably getting an error before or it is not executing it.

Comment: I looked on my console, I don't get any error. Do you know the reason why it isn't getting executing?

Comment: From your I read that you want to disabile an option when you choose any option. Meanwhile, try to see if normally, without onchange it is disabled.

Comment: Yes if I put it in a <script> directly after my <select>, it works. But if I have it in my function which is called onchange, than it doesn't work. But it normally it shouldn't be a problem if I call it in my onchange function, should it?

Comment: console.log in your disableOption function appears in console?

Comment: Yes, I get the output <option value="Option1" id="elem1" disabled="true">Option1</option>

Comment: show all code to reproduce complete situation, pls